# Update GRUB in Arch Linux after system update fails with grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub

I recently upgraded `Arch Linux` and now it's suggesting to update `GRUB`:

```bash
...
( 9/29) upgrading grub                                                                                              [######################################################################] 100%
:: To use the new features provided in this GRUB update, it is recommended
   to install it to the MBR or UEFI. Due to potential configuration
   incompatibilities, it is advised to run both, installation and generation
   of configuration:
     $ grub-install ...
     $ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
(10/29) upgrading pango
...
```

The first problem I found is that I'm unable to update it in the same way the installation process works:

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ sudo grub-install --bootloader-id="Arch Linux" --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck --target=x86_64-efi 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

My guess here is that `/boot/efi` is not mounted because it's not in `/etc/fstab` as well, so I then execute:

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi 
mount: /boot/efi: unknown filesystem type 'vfat'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

> I'm certain I installed `GRUB` in `/boot/efi`, which was mounted from `/dev/nvme0n1p1` during the installation process.

At this point I'm not sure how to move forward. I've checked and based on some posts (which is most of the times hard to tell if the state that you are into is exactly the same whoever is answering) the kernel doesn't support that filesystem, etc.

Any pointers to move forward from here? I do have `dosfstools`, if that makes a difference for this. I would like to be able to do this now, because the last time it broke I had to go in restore mode ;) ...so I would rather do it at this stage.

---

These are the drive's filesystems/partitions:

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ sudo fdisk -l 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: Force MP500                             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ********-5952-****-B0B6-4FE0********

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   3327999   3325952  1.6G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   3328000 133351423 130023424   62G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 133351424 468862094 335510671  160G Linux filesystem
```